# Correctly place standings on leaderboard PHP

Tags: php

I have a leaderboard in PHP that sorts by score first and then wins. I have standings #'s that place users in the correct standings, but when there is a tie with a score, the # of wins trumps.

Here is the array of users for example: (with what their place should be)

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [userName] => user1 [score] => 163 [wins] => 1)   <==== 1st
[1] => Array ( [userName] => user2 [score] => 162 [wins] => 1)   <==== 2nd 
[2] => Array ( [userName] => user3 [score] => 162 [wins] => 1)   <==== 2nd
[3] => Array ( [userName] => user4 [score] => 162 [wins] => 0)   <==== 3rd
[4] => Array ( [userName] => user5 [score] => 157 [wins] => 2)   <==== 4th
[5] => Array ( [userName] => user6 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 5th
[6] => Array ( [userName] => user7 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 5th
[7] => Array ( [userName] => user8 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 5th
)
```

With what I have right now, it is placing them like so:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [userName] => user1 [score] => 163 [wins] => 1)   <==== 1st
[1] => Array ( [userName] => user2 [score] => 162 [wins] => 1)   <==== 2nd 
[2] => Array ( [userName] => user3 [score] => 162 [wins] => 1)   <==== 2nd
[3] => Array ( [userName] => user4 [score] => 162 [wins] => 0)   <==== 3rd
[4] => Array ( [userName] => user5 [score] => 157 [wins] => 2)   <==== 4th
[5] => Array ( [userName] => user6 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 5th
[6] => Array ( [userName] => user7 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 6th
[7] => Array ( [userName] => user8 [score] => 157 [wins] => 0)   <==== 7th
)
```

This is not correct, because user6, user7, and user8 should all be in 5th place.

Current code:

```
array_multisort($score, SORT_DESC, $wins, SORT_DESC, $playerTotals); //sorts by score first, and then wins

$i = 1;
$tmpScore = 0;
$tmpWins = 0;

//show place #
foreach($playerTotals as $playerID => $stats) {

if ($tmpScore < $stats[score]) $tmpScore = $stats[score];
if ($tmpWins < $stats[wins]) $tmpWins = $stats[wins];

if ($stats[score] < $tmpScore) {
 $i++;
 } elseif ($stats[wins] < $tmpWins) { 
 $i++;
 } 

$pickRatio = $stats[score] . '/' . $possibleScoreTotal;
$pickPercentage = number_format((($stats[score] / $possibleScoreTotal) * 100), 2) . '%';

//display users/stats

echo '<tr><td>' . $i . '. &nbsp;&nbsp;' . $stats[userName] . '</td><td>' . $stats[wins] . '</td><td>' . $pickRatio . ' (' . $pickPercentage . ')</td></tr>';
$tmpScore = $stats[score];
 }
}
echo '</div>' . "\n";
```

The solution is probably starung me right in the face, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: can you share arrays please?

Comment: Which arrays? I already provided the needed arrays.

Comment: okok, shouldn't you add a "position" key to your array where you would store the position? it would be easier for you this way. Then, in your loop, you could build your HTML table and only output the position in another TD

Comment: I think your problem is that if do < instead of <= (smaller instead of smaller OR equal to) so the i is incremented.

Comment: I already tried that, makes it worse.

Comment: When I try your code I find that possibleScoreTotal is not defined (for pickRatio)

Comment: That is gathered from a function on another php file. It isn't necessary to have for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I found the answer, I'll post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your Loop, you have this part:

```
if ($stats["score"] < $tmpScore) {
    $i++;
} else if ($stats["wins"] < $tmpWins) {
    $i++;
}
```

What's happening there is that your `$tmpWins`, once it reach the player `user5` (id = 4), the variable `$tmpWins` is = 2. So, when it reaches the player with ID 5,6 and 7, it compares if their number of win (0) is smaller then `$tmpWins` (2), so the `$i` is incrementing. I think the logic is the problem right there. You order it at first by score, so you can always compare with the last score, but your array isn't ordered by wins.

Here is what I did to correct it :

```
<?php
 $possibleScoreTotal = 200;
 $i = 1;
 $tmpScore = 0;
 $previousWin = 0;

 //show place #
 echo '<table>';
 foreach($playerTotals as $playerID => $stats) {

    if ($tmpScore < $stats["score"]) $tmpScore = $stats["score"];

    if ($stats["score"] < $tmpScore) {
        $i++;
    } else if ($stats["wins"] < $previousWin) {
       $i++;
    }

    $previousWin = $stats['wins'];
    $pickRatio = $stats["score"] . '/' . $possibleScoreTotal;
    $pickPercentage = number_format((($stats["score"] / $possibleScoreTotal) * 100), 2) . '%';

    //display users/stats
    echo '<tr><td style="padding: 20px;">' . $i . '. &nbsp;&nbsp;' . $stats["userName"] . '</td><td>' . $stats["wins"] . '</td><td>' . $pickRatio . ' (' . $pickPercentage . ')</td></tr>';
    $tmpScore = $stats["score"];
}
echo '</table>';
```

This way, you're basically comparing if the win is greater then the last, it's a good way since your array is already ordered by score, so you only have to know that if the score is lower then the last score, is the number of win greater then it also?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I was working on something similar last night and I was missing the `$previousWin = $stats['wins'];` part. Thanks again!

Comment: It's my pleasure ! Yeah sometimes it's hard to figure solution when you're deep in it eheh, I like to stop at a problem, work on something else and come later, often it's easier to find the answer this way I found